# How to add launch options to an .arm64 executable without using the terminal on MacOS

Tags: macos, executable, arm64

I would like to know if someone know how to launch an .arm64 executable with a launch option (in this case "+set fs_game ...") without using a terminal ?
I know that you can do that in windows configuring the .exe but I don't find an alternative for MacOS.

Comment: Is this a `.app` bundle or a raw executable file?

Comment: Both. Since my .app bundle execute an .arm64 executable, if you have a solution to one of them it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few workarounds, but no actual feature that'd make this clean or easy.

---

If you have a `.app` bundle, you can redirect through a shell script that appends some arguments. If you have an Info.plist with this:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>binary</string>
```

Then you'll want to change it to:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>binary_</string>
```

And create a `Contents/MacOS/binary_` like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
"$(dirname "$0")/binary" +set fs_game "$@";
```

And give it a `chmod +x`.

That'll work no matter how you launch the app, but it will invalidate any existing code signature, so if your app was signed, you'll have to re-sign it.

---

If you have a standalone binary or if you can't afford to break the code signature, then basically the only option is to make a separate thing that invokes it the way you want. Write a bash script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a path/to/your.app --args +set fs_game;
```

Give it `chmod +x` and turn it into a separate app. This will obviously only work when invoked via that separate app, but it works with any kind of binary, and without the need to re-sign anything (and the separate app should only show up in your dock for a split second, then vanish again).

Comment: Thank you very much It work ! However there are files that the bundle needs that stand in the same folder than the bundle but it can't find them now probably because we run the script from inside the bundle, do you have an idea to fix this ? And last question, what does signing mean and what is it for ?

Comment: The script shouldn't change the working directory, but I guess try and put a `cd "$(dirname "$(dirname "$0")")"` in there. As for code signing, see [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I know it's quite a long time but it's just  to say if others come here that the problem of the working directory does not come from the script but because we need to put the app bundle into the Application folder  and it will solve this problem.